Are there quantum computing algorithms specialized for machine learning applications?
I've heard that some companies are attempting to utilize quantum computing algorithms for machine learning tasks (ex:protein folding and drug discovery). As far as I know, quantum computing has been primarily specialized for specific problems like prime factorization (e.g., Shor's algorithm) or the quantum Fourier transform. I haven't encountered quantum algorithms specifically designed for machine learning.
Is my understanding correct? Have there been breakthroughs that enable quantum computing to be applied to machine learning? If so, could you provide examples of such algorithms or explain how quantum computing can benefit machine learning?
I hesitated whether it is physics question, as this is about quantum computing. However, this topic may as well considered as data-science topic. If my post is off-topic here, let me know.

Did you check Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_machine_learning

@ConnorBehan Oh yes, but as you can easily check in the top of article, several Wikipedia policies are not held in it. Furthermore, it seems to me that the point of view of the author is prevalent in it.

Many quantum algorithms seem to be doing a kind of resonance frequency finding while at the same time damping the rest of the unwanted frequencies (Shor, Grover, etc). Could you clarify what "quantum machine learning" is trying to do in this frequency finding paradigm? What is machine learning's tweaking of the weights trying to achieve in this scheme?

Scott Aaronson's blog is a good place for quantum computing news, eg https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=8375

@K.R.Park which point of view are you saying is "prevalent" in the article? It seems relatively fair to me. By the way, not sure if you are aware, but there's also a dedicated quantum computing StackExchange: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com. You might be interested in some of the resources and discussions in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-enhanced-machine-learning and https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning
